# Switch case in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I'm trying to do multi step form with a switch case but I don't know why changing the state with nextPrev doesn't change the case.

```
export const FormSteps = ({items, pending}) => {
    const [step, setStep] = useState (2)
    const nextStep = () =>{
        setStep(prev=>({
            ...prev,
            step: step + 1
        }))
    }
    const prevStep = ()=>{
        setStep(prev=>({
            ...prev,
            step: step-1
        }))
    }
    switch (step){
        case 1:
            return(
                <StepOne 
                nextStep={nextStep}
                />
            )
        case 2:
            return(
                <StepTwo
                nextStep={nextStep}
                prevStep={prevStep}
                />
            )
        case 3:
            return(
                <StepThree 
                nextStep={nextStep}
                prevStep={prevStep}
                />
        )
        default:
            return null
    }
}
export default FormSteps
```

Comment: You're setting the new state as an object, but the state is just a number at the start. Just `setStep(prev => prev + 1)` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing a number in your state, not an object. Try this:

```
const nextStep = () =>{
    setStep(v => v + 1)
}
const prevStep = ()=>{
    setStepv(v => v - 1)
}
```